# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5300-200-0' for key 'CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID',

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, magento2.4.6, duplicate

After Upgrade Magento version to 2.4.6-p1 ,
I am getting error on executing setup:upgrade command :

Error :

> Unable to apply data patch
> Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes
> for module Magento_Catalog. Original exception message:
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '5300-200-0' for key
> 'MGCP_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID',
> query was: INSERT  INTO `mgcp_catalog_product_entity_text`

please help me about this

Thank you.